# Unable to access the main site collection (inside SharePoint on-premises server) outside the server network

Tags: 2013, administration, authentication, central-administration, iis

I am facing this problem inside our customer's on-premises sharepoint server 2013:-

1. when i try to access the main site collection using the servername `http://serverABC/`, from the sharepoint server itself i was prompted to enter username/password, and i access the site correctly.
2. when i try to access the main site collection using the servername `http://serverABC/`, from a server within the customer's network, I was prompted to enter username/password, and i access the site correctly.
3. But the problem when i try to access the main site collection using the servername `http://serverABC/`, from a server outside the customer network (from my PC), i was prompted to enter username/password as follow:-

[image]

4. but when i enter the username/password, i will be prompted to enter the username/password again for 3 times, then i got this page:-
   [image]

Now inside my PC i try to ping the sharepoint server ip and i got correct reply. so the server ip is accessible from my PC, and i have changed my hosts file inside my PC as follow:-

> 192.**.***.2** servernameABC

So seems the server is accessible from my PC (since i can ping the IP + when i try accessing the main site collection i was prompted to enter username/password and i did not get http not found error). but not sure why i can not login to the sites? and i keep getting username/password popup for 3 times then i got `http 401 error`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a proxy configured in your Internet Options of Internet Explorer. This will bypass any HOSTS-Entries and ping-checks.

Comment: but if there is a proxy settings preventing me from accessing the server, will this show a popup to enter user name and password? and seems this popup is from sharepoint site, which means i can reach the sharepoint site? or this is not necessary ?

Comment: The Password-Window says something about "level_15_access". I've never seen this associated with SharePoint. Googling for that gives tons of Cisco-related results.

Comment: so is the CISCO setting that need to be fixed on my PC (my network) or on the destination network ? or we can not tell from the message?

Comment: It should be enough to remove the proxy from your IE-Settings to reach SharePoint. But this will likely break InternetConnection on that client. If this doesn't work, you must talk to the proxy-admins.

Comment: I tried to remove the proxy from IE-settings but did not fix the issue. now i checked with our system admins, and they mentioned that since i can connect to the site from a server within the customer's network, but not from outside , and i can ping the IP from outside. then there are some settings on IIS to fix this,, although i am not sure if this is correct..

Comment: Are you accessing Customers Server via Internet or is your PC Placed inside customers LAN?

Comment: i am not sure how this is exactly configured.. but inside our company office we can access our customers servers (such as doing remote desktop, reach the ip address),, so i am not directly inside the customer LAN, but rather from our office we can access the customer servers.. but i am not sure how this is exactly configured...

Comment: You should talk to your and your customers network guys. I'm sure the solution can be found there. If you still want to dig deeper by yourself, you could take a Fiddler-Trace. Maybe it tells you more about which active network-devices (Proxys, Reverse-Proxies, Firewalls, NAT-Devices, etc.) you are talking to between your PC and customers SharePoint-Server. As already mentioned, i'd bet you talk to a Cisco-Device. But as those boxes are highly featured, they could be configured to any mode mentioned above.